# How to enable autologon in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, passwords, automatic-logon

I have tried typing the following:

> control userpasswords2

however it only brings up the control panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How To Automatically Log On To a User Account in Windows 7**

- Click on Start and then enter the following command in the search box:

  ```
    netplwiz
  ```

  Press the ENTER key.

  This command will load the Advanced User Accounts control panel applet.
- In the Users tab, uncheck the box next to **Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer**.
- Click on the **Apply** button at the bottom of the User Accounts window.
- When the Automatically Log On dialog box appears, enter the user name you wish to automatically login to Windows 7 with. Then enter your account password in the two fields where it's asked.

  Click the **OK** button.
- Click **OK** on the User Accounts window to complete the process.

  From now on, when your PC starts up, Windows 7 will logon automatically.

[Source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/auto-logon-windows-7.htm)