# After Sleep or Hibernate — how can my Windows 10 Home laptop awake, and resume, directly at desktop?

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 Home (Version 10.0.19043) laptop has NO password. **Do not ask me to add password to this backup laptop.** After I Sleep or Hibernate my desktop, when ever I turn it back, I see this screen. Then I must simply click "Sign in", before the laptop proceeds to my Desktop. **But how can I remove this aimless "Sign In" screen?** ***How can I command laptop to ALWAYS wake up right at Desktop?***

Undoubtedly, forcing me to click "Sign in" on this screen is foolish and pointless! Why bother "Sign in" when I got no password? Why not just proceed directly to Desktop!!??!?

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound done.

Comment: Have you tried setting a default user as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/88263/how-to-enable-autologon-in-windows-7)?

Answer (score 2):

> But how can I remove this aimless "Sign In" screen?

Start, Settings, Accounts, Sign in Options:

Set Require Sign in to Never.

Also uncheck the setting below this "Allow Windows to Lock your device ..... "

Restart the computer after you change this selection.

[image: Sign in selection]

.

My advice, however, in 2020 and beyond (yes we are in 2021) is to use a Passwords. More systems of all kinds are enforcing this.

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work for me. Pls see https://superuser.com/q/1691809?

Comment: You are probably using a domain connected system where this option can be enabled or disabled in Group Policy.

Comment: Also enable passwords . It is easy to do and the vast majority of people use passwords. I suggest you do the same and make it a habit.

Comment: Pls Do not ask me to add password to this backup laptop.

Comment: No passwords = screwed up unfiixable logins.