# Why do my "Sign-in options" lack "Require sign-in"?

Tags: login-screen

**Do not ask me to add password to this backup laptop.** It uses Windows 10 Home Version 10.0.19043. Following is user [John](https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john)'s [Sign-in options screen](https://superuser.com/a/1691437).

[image]

***Why does mine below differ? Why does mine lack "Require sign-in" and the dropbox for "When PC wakes up from sleep"?***

[image]

Comment: My screen shot (first above) is true for Windows 10 Pro latest and Windows 11 Pro.  What version of Windows do you have?  Home or Pro? (or maybe Enterprise or Education)?

Comment: @John pls see my edited post.

Comment: @ElVaf - The answer to this requires you to set a password.  There isn’t another answer to your question, as the option, requires a password in order to exist.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does mine below differ?

The option will not be listed if the user account does not have a password set.

> Why does mine lack "Require sign-in" and the Dropbox for "When PC wakes up from sleep"?

The account you are using does not have a password set.  My suggestion would be to set a password, then configure the account as the default account (allowing the machine to automatically be logged into), thus allowing you to set the option to whatever option you want.

Comment: Both Ramhound and I have suggested using passwords. No password in an Admin User (The Windows first user is always admin) is a gaping security hole